# openssl 1.1.1g: Allow usage of insecure client certs

Tags: ssl, openssl

I need to connect to an old server so I had to lower default security level to `DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1` & `MinProtocol = TLSv1.0` (as per [openssl: Allow usage of insecure client certs](https://serverfault.com/questions/957931/openssl-allow-usage-of-insecure-client-certs)).
That used to work as expected but is not working anymore recently.

I'm running openssl 1.1.1g and I'm getting `SSL routines:tls_process_ske_dhe:dh key too small` when connecting to this old server whatsoever...

I can access the server using firefox once I toggle `security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha` in `about:config`

Has there been changes which will prevent that from working now?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can access the server using firefox once I toggle security.ssl3.dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha in about:config

Answer (score 0):

Please disregard, I fixed my problem and it had nothing to do with openssl update or config... PEBKAC